# In javascript ES2015 extending a class, must I re-import all dependancies?

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I'm using alot of similar classes which all use the same dependencies so they all start with the same list of ES2015 import statements. I wonder is, using inheritance or something, I can make it so that this is only needed in the parent to prevent redundant code? Note that I use 1 class per file.

```
import angular from 'angular;
import {subscribeReducer} from '../shared/helpers/reduce.helper';
import newhomeReducer from './newhome.reducer';

import {subscribeSaga} from '../shared/helpers/saga.helper';
import newhomeSagas from './newhome.saga';

class Newhome{...something...};
```

and then class 2:

```
import angular from 'angular;
import {subscribeReducer} from '../shared/helpers/reduce.helper';
import currenthomeReducer from './newhome.reducer';

import {subscribeSaga} from '../shared/helpers/saga.helper';
import currenthomeSagas from './newhome.saga';

class Currenthome{...something...};
```

Comment: You only need to import what you reference, so if you don't reference something, then you don't need to import..  Also a good editor, will let you know what you have not referenced,.. eg. I'm using Atom.IO, with eslint, and if I add an import that is not referenced, it will let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to re-import your dependencies, unless you use them in the child class too.

For example, if your child class was only:

```
class Currenthome extends Newhome {}
```

then you don't have to re-import your dependencies; but if you use them in the child class:

```
class Currenthome extends Newhome {
  someMethod() {
    angular.doSomething();
  }
}
```

then you have to import them.